# Python:Excel unreadable content in file

Tags: python-2.7

When I try to download excel by web from python `xlsxwriter`. It given me the message

> Excel found unreadable content in file. Do you want to recover the
>   contents of this workbook?

when I opened the file excel which i download. Please help me to solve it. Thanks

Comment: Not enough message, can you provide more about this file? (maybe post its link?)

Comment: and by the way, who gives you this message? Office Excel or xlsxwriter?